# Why Application-Level Resources doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to implement application level resources in my pages, but seems it's not working.

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
<Style TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
   <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The Page

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
...
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" >
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I would like the system tray should look the way its styled in App.xaml, but it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: In the PhoneApplicationPage you need to set the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application-wide implicit styles work on Windows Phone since Mango. The thing you need to remember is that implicit style is applied to TargetType only, not to its descendants. Your Pages are new classes that **inherit** from PhoneApplicationPage. What will work is:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="local:MainPage">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor" Value="Black"/>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

But obviously you would have to define that for every Page in your project, which makes it useless. For Pages it's best to use Explicit Styles (with x:Key):

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="PageStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor" Value="Black"/>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and for every Page in your project simply:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
  Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have pages which I would like to use the same background, foreground and system tray, Do I need to explicitly style individual page? Then why we have application level style?

Comment: @ARH I updated my answer. the **default** aplication-level styles work for Buttons, TextBoxes etc., they also work for PhoneApplicationPage, but in your project there is no UIElement that is PhoneApplicationPage and **is not a class derived from it**.